# Unable to connect to a cloud service after publishing via visual studio

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-cloud-services

I am trying to run this [sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/tree/master/Samples/V1.0Samples/LocalMediaSamples/AudioVideoPlaybackBot): The documentation states that I need to publish the solution. This works and visual studio reports success. However, the cloud service site URL is unreachable. I don't know if this is because the application doesn't work or the machine is unreachable due to some security configuration. RDP to cloud service also fails. How do I figure out the security configuration associated with this cloud service?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is a Windows 7 issue. RDP from a windows 10 machine works. Windows 7 EOL is still at least a year away though.